# What is different about the VS debug browser compared to the normal browser?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-debugging

I am calling a controller method to log a user on. If I call the published app from the server in a regular browser, it fails. However it works locally and If i call the server from the browser spawned for debugging, it works. I want to know what is functionally different between these two browsers so I can narrow down the issue. Thanks!

Comment: What is the "debug browser"?  Doesn't debugging a web app just launch your web browser?  To narrow down the issue it sounds like you need to define what "it fails" means.  Don't try to determine *all possible differences* between two environments.  Focus on the *actual error*.

Comment: If the browser is identical, then it wouldn't make sense that I have an error in one and don't have it in another with a copy/pasted url. It is my understanding that the visual studio browser is somewhat different to account for the transfer of javascript breakpoints and such. Since this error is happening only under one circumstance, I assumed it would be productive to understand what is different about this circumstance than the one in which it is working.

Comment: Everything depends on what the error actually is.  Which is what, exactly?

Comment: There is no error being thrown. The method checks a table for a token and if it matches, it logs the user in. It is simply redirecting to the login page which is the behavior of a failed login. It is not failing locally under any circumstances.

Comment: No *exception* doesn’t mean no *error*.  If the system is behaving unexpectedly, that’s an error.  That’s also where you begin your investigation.  What specific operation is behaving differently?  What line of code?  What are the runtime values in the working and non-working versions?  Are they different?  Where do they come from?  The root cause may indeed be environmental, even browser related.  But “list all possible differences” is not how you investigate the issue.  Start with the actual error.

Comment: The error is only happening on the published app from the server and I wouldn't know how to debug it down to a specific line or really get any information about the failure so I am attempting to debug it using knowledge I do have or can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the "debug browser" and the normal one.

The difference is when you run the application from Visual Studio, it hosts the application so the browser can read it. When you try to access the same URL without a running host application, it won't be available because there is nothing listening for incoming requests from the browser. Exactly how it is hosted depends on the settings of the Properties/Web tab of the project.

[image]

Comment: Alright. Good to know that there is nothing functionally different. That gives me a starting point. Thanks.

Comment: @DevDevDev, If it is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)